# Unable to load static pages

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to add some front-end to my project which so far has only been back-end. So i added a 'views' folder and added some .pug files just to try it out but when i try to render the files i get the following error:

```
{ Error: Failed to lookup view "index.pug" in views directory "/app/views"

at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
server_1       |   view: 
server_1       |    View {
server_1       |      defaultEngine: 'pug',
server_1       |      ext: '.pug',
server_1       |      name: 'index.pug',
server_1       |      root: '/app/views',
server_1       |      engine: [Function],
server_1       |      path: undefined } }
```

I can't find the code where root is specified as /app/views and since my project doesn't contain a "app" folder it wont render my .pug files. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: This may not help, but if a framework gives you a project structure try to follow it, unless you have a very compelling reason not to.

Comment: Is it possible to have code which generate this error such as, how you set the engine, how you set the template engine or you are using express generator?